# replace('\n','') does not work for import to .txt format

Tags: python, django

The place where I put this code belongs to an import page.And here there is data in the data I want to import in `.txt` format, but this data contains the `\n` character.

```
if request.method == "POST":

    txt_file = request.FILES['file']

    if not txt_file .name.endswith('.txt'):
        messages.info(request,'This is not a txt file')

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('latin-1')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(io_string, delimiter='\t',quotechar="|")

    for column in csv_reader:
        b = Module_Name(
            user= request.user,
            a = column[1],
            b = column[2],
            c = column[3],
            d = column[4],
            e = column[5],
            f = column[6],
            g = column[7],
            h = column[8],
            )
            b.save()
    messages.success(request,"Successfully Imported...")
    return redirect("return:return_import")
```

This can be called the full version of my code. To explain, there is a \n character in the data that comes here as column[1]. This file is a .txt file from another export. And in this export column[1];

```
This is
a value
```

and my django `localhost new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?` gives a warning and aborts the import to the system.

Comment: Can you edit your post to add your `io_string`?

Comment: Perhaps the line endings were CRLF originally so now you still have a `\r` in the data that you didn't clean?

Comment: I tried \r but it doesn t work

Answer (score 0):

the csv reader iterates over rows, not columns. So if you want to append the data from a given column together, you must iterate over all the rows first. For example:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

io_string = "this is , r0 c1\r\na value, r1 c2\r\n"

io_string = StringIO(io_string)
rows = csv.reader(io_string)

column_0_data = []
for row in rows:
    column_0_data.append(row[0])

print("".join(column_0_data))
```

the rest of your code looks iffy to me, but that is off topic.